# Como filtrar uma HashMap retornando outra HashMap usando Java 8 lambda?

Tags: java, expressões-lambda, java-8, filter

O seguinte código percorre um `Set` e filtra apenas os objetos que o `isActive()` é `true`.

```
public Set<InvoiceLineDocument> getActiveLines() {
        Set<InvoiceLineDocument> activeLines = new HashSet<>();

        for (InvoiceLineDocument lineDocument : lineDocuments) {
            if (lineDocument.isActive())
                activeLines.add(lineDocument);
        }

        return activeLines;
    }
```

Como converto essa implementação para o Java 8 [`stream().filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)?

Comment: InvoiceLineDocument é sua classe ou de alguma lib?

Comment: É uma classe minha.

Comment: Já tentou com `lineDocuments.stream().filter(x -> x.isActive()).collect(Collectors.toSet());` ?.

Comment: Poxa, não tinha visto o toSet(). É isso mesmo, deu certo. Não seria melhor criar uma resposta pra marcar como "resolvido"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se pretende filtrar os que estão ativos com `stream` e `filter`, apenas precisa de utilizar o método `isActive` dentro do `filter` e acumular o resultado num set com [`toSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet--):

```
lineDocuments.stream().filter(x -> x.isActive()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi sua dúvida corretamente basta você fazer o seguinte:

```
Set<LineDocument> set = lineDocuments.stream().filter( l -> l.isActive()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```